# javascript combine variables into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could someone help me with this javascript. I have two variables, with commaseparated words.

```
var names = "Verwerkende industrie, Retail, Primaire producent, Out of home, Groothandel, Grondstof, Consument, Bewerkende industrie";
var numbers = "9, 3, 4, 2, 7, 9, 3, 2";
```

I would like to combine them into an array that should end up looking like this

```
var combined = [
                ['Verwerkende industrie', 9], 
                ['Retail', 3], 
                ['Primaire producent', 4], 
                ['Out of home', 2], 
                ['Groothandel', 7], 
                ['Grondstof', 9], 
                ['Consument', 3], 
                ['Bewerkende industrie', 2]
            ];
```

Comment: The line for `numbers` is not valid Javascript syntax. Is it supposed to be an array? Or a string like `names`? Also, are you sure you wouldn't rather have an array of objects than an array of arrays?

Comment: ahh, sorry. It is also a string like names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var names = "Verwerkende industrie, Retail, Primaire producent, Out of home, Groothandel,      Grondstof, Consument, Bewerkende industrie";
var numbers = "9, 3, 4, 2, 7, 9, 3, 2";

var namesArray = names.split(","); //split the string at ','. split() returns an array of result
var numbersArray = numbers.split(",");

var resultArray = []; //array to hold result

//since the namesArray and numbersArray are the same length, you can use one for-loop
for (var i=0, len=namesArray.length; i < len; i++) {
  resultArray[i] = [namesArray[i], parseInt(numbersArray[i])];
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.. And even with line comments

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
var names = "Verwerkende industrie, Retail, Primaire producent, Out of home, Groothandel, Grondstof, Consument, Bewerkende industrie";
var numbers = "9, 3, 4, 2, 7, 9, 3, 2";

names = names.split(',');
numbers = numbers.split(',');
var combined = [];
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
  combined.push([names[i], parseInt(numbers[i])]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = "Verwerkende industrie, Retail, Primaire producent, Out of home, Groothandel, Grondstof, Consument, Bewerkende industrie";
var numbers = "9, 3, 4, 2, 7, 9, 3, 2";

function zip(arrays) {
    return arrays[0].map(function(_,i){
        return arrays.map(function(array){return array[i]})
    });
}

// paramert = array
zip([
 names.split(/,\s+/),
 numbers.split(/,\s+/).map(function (i) { return parseInt(i); })
]);
```

Comment: This does not give the desired array. For one the whitespace is not stripped, secondly the numbers will be strings (the example output states they are number types).

Comment: @IngoBürk sorry for the mix up. I was in a hurry

Comment: quite close. When I console.log it it gives me the structure, but all numbers are undefined in the array

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately JavaScript doesn't have a 'zip' function, but you can do the same thing like this:

```
var namesArr = names.split(", ");
var numbersArr = numbers.split(", ").map(function (s) { return parseInt(s); });
var combined = [];
for (var i = 0; i < namesArr.length; i++)
{
    combined[i] = [namesArr[i], numbersArr[i]];
}
```

Comment: close but some of them result in a NaN